# Standardize dataframes heading

Tags: pandas

I have a list of dataframes that I want to conduct data analysis on. However, some of the column names have odd spaces in front and after causing errors. I want to remove all these spaces but was having trouble finding a solution. I think that putting all the dataframes into one would be difficult because they all have different amounts of columns, but do share some column titles.

Comment: It would be better to provide a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.columns.str.strip()` to remove the external spaces.

In your list `l`:

```
for i, d in enumerate l:
    l[i].columns = d.columns.str.strip()

df_all = pd.concat(l)
```